# I can't find my functions in outlet connection.. Do know how to solve this error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, outlet

[image]

```
public float 내각의합구하기(int 꼭짓점) {
    return 180 * (꼭짓점 - 2);
}

public float 대각선그어서생기는삼각형개수(int 꼭짓점) {
    return 꼭짓점 - 2;
}

public float 뿔의부피구하기(float 밑면 , float 높이) {
    return (밑면 * 높이) / 3;
}
```

I was written like this functions about 40.
I was trying to add these functions on Onclick().
But i can't find them.
What is the problem?
Help me.

Comment: Onclick doesn’t do anything with return values. So I thought they needed to be void

Comment: Thanks to you, I finally solved the problem!

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Comment: Also in general I strongly strongly recommend you start coding in english! It is **the** international language for communication and programing. Especially e.g. when coming here an ask about your code it is extremely hard for everyone else to even understand what your code is supposed to do ;)